# Windows timers, how is the end time determined?

Tags: windows, events, timer, timeout

How does Windows manage its timers.
For example if I had a timeout of 1 minute, does it mark (count) the time, or does it set a wakeup time for when that time is reached?

The reason that I ask, is that we have an application that sometimes fails, and this quite often occurs when the machines time is being set forward by close on to 60 seconds, by something currently unknown.

```
The system time has changed to ?2018?-?08?-?16T22:07:21.184000000Z from ?2018?-?08?-?16T22:06:22.931000700Z.

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" Guid="{A68CA8B7-004F-D7B6-A698-07E2DE0F1F5D}" /> 
  <EventID>1</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000010</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-08-16T22:07:21.184000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>59985</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1636" ThreadID="1712" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>PDC2FEP007.domain</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="NewTime">2018-08-16T22:07:21.184000000Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="OldTime">2018-08-16T22:06:22.931000700Z</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Obviously, we will try and hunt down the offending time setter, but in the interim, I was just curious

Answer (score 0):

I found following on the internet : 
"According to MSDN, An application uses a timer to schedule an event for a window after a specified time has elapsed. It means that if we create a timer and specify a time interval of uElapse milliseconds, it will do "something" every uElapse milliseconds, until we destroy it. It is up to us to specify what "something" is. "

So, I assume from this particularly "It will do "something" every uElapse milliseconds, until we destroy it" that it is counting every millisecond.